# How to check is connection encrypted

Tags: postgresql, ssl, postgresql-9.1, psqlodbc

Using old Postgres server

> PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit

Server has symlinks `server.crt` and `server.key` in data directory `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1./main` and `ssl=true` in `postgresql.conf` file.

Server is running in old Debian squeeze.

Client accesses server from Windows 10 using psqlODBC driver with

```
sslmode=allow
```

in connection string.

How to verify that connection is encrypted? Is there some command in client or server or can some protocol analyzer used if no easier way?

Comment: What about allowing **only** ssl connection? Then you can be sure the connection is encrypted

Comment: If you don't know how to configure it properlly you are reduced to sniffing. The traffic. Best to learn how to comfigure it first. Off topic.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I added sslmode=require to psqlodbc connection string an it worked without issues. I need verify is connection encrypted, network admin complains that it is not encrypted. Maybe some postgres query can used.

Comment: I am talking about doing that in `pg_hba.conf` to refuse any non-ssl connection (essentially change all `host` entries to `hostssl` and then non-ssl connections aren't possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to upgrade to 9.5 or above and look into the `pg_stat_ssl` view. That will tell you if and how the connection is encrypted.

Comment: Upgrading is not easy. Is there some query in 9.1 which can used to check is connection encrypted ? Magnus has written small extension but I'm not sure can this installed on this server.

Comment: Sniffing the network is easier.